# Using SELECT-FROM-WHERE to combine to specified columns from two tables students and advisors

Tags: mysql

This is my code:

```
SELECT Advisor.AdvisorID, 
Advisor.LastName, 
Advisor.FirstName, 
Student.LastName,
Student.FirstName, 
BirthDate, 
Gender, 
GPA
FROM advisors, students
WHERE Student.AdvisorID = Advisor.AdvisorID
ORDER BY Advisor.LastName asc, Student.LastName asc LIMIT 0, 1000
```

This is the ERROR receiving:

> 20:25:01  SELECT Advisor.AdvisorID, Advisor.LastName,
>   Advisor.FirstName, Student.LastName,Student.FirstName, BirthDate,
>   Gender, GPA FROM advisors, students WHERE Student.AdvisorID =
>   Advisors.AdvisorID ORDER BY Advisor.LastName asc, Student.LastName asc
>   LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Advisor.AdvisorID' in
>   'field list'  0.000 sec

I am trying to to combine the students and advisors tables. In students table need Student.AdvisorID, Student.LastName, Student.FirstName, BirthDate, Gender, GPA. In advisors table need Advisor.LastName, AdvisorFirstName using the SELECT statement.

Must sort by advisor name then student name.

Comment: Change it to advisors.advisorid

Answer (score 1):

the error is self explanatory ... Advisor.AdvisorID column or Advisor table doesn't exists..you are missing a s for your Advisor table which should be Advisors

Comment: I added the "s" to Advisors and still receive the same error

Comment: @LatashaPrather-Gates show us the table definition then

Comment: in my advisors table Advisors.AdvisorID is an Integer, NOT NULL

Comment: @LatashaPrather-Gates well the error says the other way...why dont you just update your question with the new query, new error and table definition? also try to change the lower case advisor to Advisor donno if that will effect anything

Comment: Thank you for your assistance I had to add a prefix and the query worked.